# google.com web pages with ".py" extension?

Tags: python, webserver

Take, for instance, `support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287`. What is that `answer.py`? How does this work? I'm 99.99% sure that browsers don't have the ability to interpret python code (yet) like javascript / PHP. So what is this? Is it some Python webframework?

Comment: Browsers don't interpret it. Server does. And it sends HTML out.

Comment: Browsers don't have the ability to interpret PHP code either.

Comment: Ahhhh. Didn't know that. So then if PHP can just be embedded in the HTML files, when does it get executed? Could you just embed python in HTML (I don't think so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you request a file that's ending in `.py` that spits out the usual HTML et. al. The file is executed on the server side, **not** in your browser.

But again, that's a URL and it could point to *any* resource. Could be anything. Like a lot of websites use pretty URLs to point you to something , except in this case it's not pretty. (Behind the scenes there are routers, rewrite rules sometimes, etc. to do this.)

Comment: Not necessarily a `file`. It is just a resource.

Comment: So when a request is sent to the server for some `.py` page, the server (maybe/probably) executes the python script, which generates the html?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this just accesses a resource called `answer.py` on the server. This naming convention is entirely up to the server - it could run a python script (most likely what is going on), or it could even be in a completely different language. In any case, all that that browser cares about is the information that is returned from that resource - HTML, CSS, XML, etc...

Comment: So can web browsers only interpret html/css/xml/javascript?

Comment: Well, in general web browsers can only execute JavaScript code, interpret HTML markup, and render CSS styles. A browser can execute code such as ActionScript or C# (.NET bytecodes?) with an additional plugin such as Flash or Silverlight. I suppose if you developed your own plugin or JavaScript runtime then the browser could execute python... but no one does that, and you get the idea.